# BPSK demodulation on scilab

Tags: matlab, demodulation, bpsk

I have a csv file which contains the time and magnitude of the BPSK modulated waveform. I now want to demodulate this. Its bitrate is fc/128 (~106 kbit/s) and the carrier frequency is fc/16 (~847 kHz). I tried demodulating it using the below code:

```
Array=csvRead('modulated_wfm.csv');
col1 = Array(:, 1);
col2 = Array(:, 2);
t1 = linspace(0,0.00165,20635);
subplot(3,1,1);

plot(t1,col2);'

T = 106000;
f = 847000;
t = 0:0.00000008:0.00165;
cosine_func = cos(2*3.14*f*t);
demodulated=col2.*(sqrt(2/T)*cosine_func);
```

I don't know what to do next. I am stuck. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know any better than you what your signal precisely looks like!

But I can tell you what I do when I'm stuck:

I plot sensible segments of my signal after each processing step. So.

Take sample 200 to 1000 of your input signal as read and plot it. Does it look like you've expected it? Can you see the expected phase jumps of bpsk? If not, you need to check your assumptions and data handling.

Move on to the next step. Does it look like you would expect? (This requires thinking about what you expect, but you'll find that is exactly what helps you here!)

Every step you move along, and think what the signal should look like after, and how it looks like before. That's actually the key to engineering this!

---

I'd go on my usual rant about how csv is certainly not an adequate format for sample storage, with all the pro-arguments falling flat the moment you exceed a couple hundred samples, and how it's inefficient, ambiguous, inaccurate and hard to parse in the presence of different locales, but I'm on mobile so I will have to manage my sadness about csv being used as sample storage format.

Comment: My signal is a BPSK modulated signal.

Comment: Is *sample frequency* **exactly** related to carrier frequency? If so, demodulation should be fairly straightforward. If not, demodulation is considerably more complex. As Marcus suggests, graphing data of an unfamiliar data set is an excellent, cautious approach. I have done this with WWVB signals where AM modulation is overlaid with BPSK modulation, and both are buried in noise. Plotting data samples was essential in evaluating demodulation steps.

Comment: @tan45 I know. I explicitly addressed that! You will need to do your plotting and analysis! Nobody else than you yourself can help you at this point.